# Nested JWT token claims

Tags: json, security, jwt

Just a quick question regarding the JWT spec and common JWT best practices. Can / should I use nested objects as JWT token claims or should I used prefixed claims? It both seems to be valid (at least it is both decoded by websites like https://jwt.io) but I am unsure if there are guidelines on which of the two options to choose.

**Option 1:**

```
{
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "user.firstName": "John",
  "user.lastName": "Doe"
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
{
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "user": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Comment: The [official RFC for JWT](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-7) only mention top level standard names for the claims section.  I didn't see anything "forbidding" nested claims as you have done it in option #2 above, but I might gravitate towards option #1 here.